# how to bind isselected property of tabitem in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 5 tabs on my `mainwindow.xaml`. On each tab there is a button. On button click I have to change the view to next tab.

Can I do this (changing the tabs on button click) in the xaml itself by binding `IsSelected` property of the `TabItem` to my previous button command property (I am enabling/disabling the buttons by using commands)?

My `CanExecute` will check the `IsEnabled` property of the buttons.

I can do this in the code behind by changing the `SelectedTabIndex` or `SelectedTabItem`. But can I do it in the xaml to follow MVVM pattern?

If my question is not a valid question, please ignore it.

Note: My tabs are not from templates.

Comment: You can do this in your ViewModel. Are the tabs dynamic? or a fixed amount?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. My tabs are fixed.

Comment: TabControl.SelectedItem should hold the view model or model that is the DataContext for that particular TabItem.  With most items controls, you'd bind ItemsSource or similar property to a list of items that are displayed in the control, then SelectedItem tracks the item from the list that the user has selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `Style` of TabControl:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding SelectedIndex}"/>
</Style>
```

Bind same `Command` to all buttons and on every click keep incrementing the `SelectedIndex` property in your `ViewModel`.

**Property in ViewModel:**

```
private int selectedIndex;

public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return selectedIndex; }
    set { selectedIndex = value;
    UpdateProperty("SelectedIndex");
    }
}
```

**Command Action:**

```
SelectedIndex++;
if (SelectedIndex == 5)
{
    SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

> ***check for `SelectedIndex = 5` cause your tab are fixed.else you have to bind count of items in a property of `ViewModel` and then put a check.***